# When boolean method returns False, it still moves to the next Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a boolean method and when it returns false, I expect it to stay in the same activity (so user can fill in the blank fields). If boolean is true, then it should move to the next activity.

I'm still new at coding.

```
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
               switch (item.getItemId()) {
                  case R.id.calculate:
              switch (spinnerAPos) {

                    case 1:

                        Y = x * b;
                        break;
                   case 2:
                          etc...
                     break
                          }

         if(checkAnswer(y));
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("A", Math.round(Y * 100.0) / 100.0);
                startActivity(intent);
               }
            return true ;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

    public boolean checkAnswer(double y){

    boolean pass = false;
    if (y == 0 ){
     editText.setError("add a number greater than Zero");
      }
  pass = false;
    }else{
          pass =true;
        }
          return pass;
        }
         }
```

Comment: Please, add your question/problem to the question body

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are not actually evaluating the `if` block.

Change your `if` block to:

```
if(checkAnswer(y)){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("A", Math.round(Y * 100.0) / 100.0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Your code had `if(checkAnswer(y));` which caused the code to just go to the next line of code, eg. directly to the `Intent`.

---

In general, there are a few issues with your code. Perhaps it is just because you reduced your code to an example, but an example: you have no semicolon (`;`) after the `break` in the `switch` block "case 2:".

---

**EDIT**: actually, I'm surprised your code compiles! Your `checkAnswer()` method has an illegal `if` block construction: you have `pass = false;` between the `if` and the `else` portion. Please, post code that will compile when asking a question.

Comment: Yes that did it. THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Comment: @beth If you found this answer helpful, be sure to upvote and accept it!

Comment: @beth:: you don't have to have reputation to accept an answer to a question you posted. There should be a grey check mark next to the answer. In order to accept the answer toggle the check mark from greyed out to filled in. (You only need reputation to Up- or Down vote a post.)